# How to change the order of the OK/Cancel buttons?

Tags: gnome, window-buttons

I'm new in Ubuntu. So far, I used only Windows. In Ubuntu irritates me order of dialog buttons: OK / Cancel. In Windows OK button is first and Cancel is second button. In Ubuntu it is vice versa. How can I change it? What should I do to change it and set sequence to OK / Cancel in all dialogs?

Comment: blame Microsoft for getting it wrong 5-10 years before the Right Way was defined ;) Oh wait it was only following IBM-CUA which was influenced by Apple, so it's probably Steve Jobs fault. I just sent him an angry letter o.O

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't change that (without changing the program). It's the order recommended by the [GNOME Human Interface Guidelines](http://library.gnome.org/devel/hig-book/stable/) and therefore The Right Way To Do It in Ubuntu.